# Sum of Digits of a Column in R

Tags: r

I implemented a function in R which gives the sum of all the digits in the R till the sum is a single digit.

i wrote this

```
ds <- function(x) {
    c <- sum(floor(x / 10^(0:(nchar(x) - 1))) %% 10)
    if(c>9)
    {c<-ds(c)}
    return(c)
}
```

i have my data in a dataframe column and i want to get the sum in new column
this is the column which contains the number

```
 records$am1
[1]  624727  262453 4237731 1079780
```

but when i use this code

```
records<-records%>%mutate(V7=ds(am1))
```

i get this error code

```
Warning messages:
1: In 0:(nchar(x) - 1) :
  numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
2: In x/10^(0:(nchar(x) - 1)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

and for all rows value of v7 is set as 5.

however if i apply this function as

```
ds(624727)
```

i  get the correct output.

Please help me to apply it to the column

Answer (score 1):

When used in `mutate()` your function will receive a vector of all the values at once. Your function needs to be able to take a vector and return a vector. Your function doesn't do well with multiple values `ds(c(624727, 1112222))`.The easiest way to make that happen is to use `Vectorize()`. Maybe

```
records %>% mutate(V7=Vectorize(ds)(am1))
```

Or you could use the rowwise option in dplyr

```
records %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(V7=ds(am1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
records %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(V7=ds(am1))
```